# Nativescript w/ NG2: *ngFor loop to create rows in a GridLayout

Tags: angular, nativescript, grid-layout, tabular, ngfor

I am trying to make what I thought would be a simple table by doing the following:

```
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*,*,auto" width="100%" class="table-body">
  <Label col="0" row="0" text="Date"></Label>
  <Label col="1" row="0" text="Previous Owner"></Label>
  <Label col="2" row="0" text="Price" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
  <template *ngFor="let sale of history; let i = index">
    <Label col="0" row="{{i+1}} [text]="sale.saleDate"></Label>
    <Label col="1" row="{{i+1}} [text]="sale.username"></Label>
    <Label col="2" row="{{i+1}} [text]="sale.price" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
  </template>
</GridLayout>
```

Sample of table I would like to create:

[image]

This code does not work but I think it shows what I am trying to do, it has been suggested to me to put the `*ngFor` inside the GridLayout tag but that won't work as it won't take the largest `sale.price` to make the column width.

I am quite surprised I am having such difficulty finding any examples to help me with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions - you can try using the Angular binding `[row]="i"` (increment +1 your index in the code behind rather than in the binding).

Still, the whole idea can be represented with [ListView](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html) which is virtualized, supports recycling out-fo-the-box and item templates..  better performance than the ng structural directives. The reason to prefer ListView instead of structural directives is well explained [here](https://medium.com/@alexander.vakrilov/faster-nativescript-listview-with-multiple-item-templates-8f903a32e48f#.9b6ujss3g)

e.g.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/release/app/common-screens-category/lists-category/multi-line-grouped/multi-line-grouped.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Although, It's too late to answer the question, But **for someone who stuck here**.

It would be better to **put the heading itself into the array** as the first element of the array and iterate the GridLayout normally.